# How to use snyk on a hosted gitlab

Tags: security, gitlab, snyk

I have tried Dependabot, to no avail. Snyk looks promising but our code is on a hosted instance of gitlab, does anyone have any idea how I could adapt the steps located in the following link, to tell snyk that it must use our hosted instance of gitlab, with the provided personal access token?

Failing that, another, different tool-recommendation would be helpful.

https://snyk.io/gitlab/

Answer (score 2):

This is done via [Snyk Broker](https://docs.snyk.io/features/integrations/snyk-broker/broker-introduction). If you're looking to replace dependabot (which does work on GitLab, if you want to post a separate question about why that's not working for you), you could also look at [Renovate Bot](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) which wouldn't require a Snyk subscription.

Comment: Thanks, I will create a separate dependabot question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463807/what-causes-this-dependabot-issue

Comment: I'm sure this is solid advice, but I've parked this, for now, so am unable to verify.